# Can you help me identifying this spider?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]
I took this picture in Ohrid, Macedonia, it is the first time I see this kind of spider here.

This spider was 2-3 cm long and was outside in urban building.

Comment: It's probably an *Araneus*, but I'm not sure about the species.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Thank you for including location information, but please edit your post to add an estimate of the size of the spider and the environment you found it in. —— The size and environment can be essential clues for identification. Thanks! 

Comment: It was 2-3 cm long and it was outside in urban building. Thank you too 

Comment: @CveteRisteska Better edit your question and insert the size and location information in the original post. Information in comments might get lost or people won't read them.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to identify it by your photo via Seek app and the result is "cross orbweaver / *Araneus diadematus*

The result seems true when it's compared to description in [this site](https://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.asp?identification=Cross-Orbweaver-Spider)

For comparision see this image:[image: By Jon Glittenberg - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=17710196]

Comment: You're welcome. I strongly recommend this app for that kind of situations.